# Create one row for every user in a Postgres table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, insert

I have a bunch of rows of users in a `users` table, for example:

```
| id |  name |
|----|-------|
|  1 | Chris |
|  2 | Max   |
|  3 | Steve |
```

For each one of these users, I'd like to create a row in another table called `user_flags`:

```
| user_id |  flag  |
|---------|--------|
|       1 | myflag |
|       2 | myflag |
|       3 | myflag |
```

Currently what I'm doing is downloading users in batches of ~100 at a time, and then doing a bulk `INSERT` query for each batch. However I think that there should be a quicker way.

**The goals:**

- Insert the flag rows as quickly as possible
- Long running queries are fine, as long as there's no table locking anywhere
- These are real-time queries, so indexes cannot be dropped
- Should be able to comfortably run over millions of user rows

Is this possible? I feel like with some smart functions it could/should be.

Comment: What should go into each new `flag` column? The string `'myflag'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would seem rather simple:

```
INSERT INTO user_flags (user_id, flag)
SELECT u.id, 'myflag'   -- or whatever to write to this field
FROM   users u
LEFT   JOIN user_flags uf ON uf.user_id = u.id
WHERE  uf.user_id IS NULL;  -- to exclude already existing
```

How to ..

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

While this is susceptible to race conditions with concurrent transactions, that should not be a problem since you are not going to execute this `INSERT` in more than *one* transaction at a time.

You might limit the operations to *n* rows per call, say 100000, simply append `LIMIT`, possibly combined with `ORDER BY`:

```
...
ORDER  BY u.id
LIMIT  100000;
```

Repeat the query until you find < 100000 rows, in separate transactions to release locks. Normally, you would do it all in one command, though, even with millions of rows.

I suggest a [`FOREIGN KEY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) constraint to enforce referential integrity - if you don't have one, yet.

```
ALTER TABLE user_flags
  ADD CONSTRAINT user_flags_user_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
  REFERENCES users(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `user_flags.user_id` to make the 1:1 relationship complete.

Comment: Amazing - thanks for this answer! I haven't used `JOIN` in inserts before, but you're absolutely right, this ain't rocket science. Good shout on race conditions. Out of interest - what was the reason behind limiting it to 100k per batch?

Comment: @ChrisHoughton: Just trying to address the parts in your question `downloading users in batches of ~100 at a time` in combination with `Should be able to comfortably run over millions of user rows`. To keep transactions and locks short, you can split this operation at will. 100,000 seems more reasonable than 100. Run inserts in separate transactions to actually release locks. I would do it in one fell swoop unless there is a compelling reason not to.